# AWS Simple Email Service (SES) Recipient Email Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, next.js, amazon-ses

I am trying to send a transactional email to the user after a successful booking of a service on a NextJs app using AWS SES.
I have created a verified identity on AWS SES using the official email of the client's business.
However, I am receiving an error stating that the recipient's email is not verified (as shown below).

[image: Error message from AWS javascript SDK]

Is the recipient email (i.e. the email of the user booking the service) supposed to be verified? Isn't it just the the source email is supposed to be verified?

Below is my code snippet:

[image: Code for sending AWS SES email]

Expect email to be sent and only source email to be verified.

Comment: Please don't add an image as code. You need you post your code.

Comment: Have you completed the verification?
See here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/creating-identities.html#just-verify-email-proc